# how to write when-checkbox-changed trigger

Tags: oracle, oracleforms

There are two distinct checkboxes named CHKBOX_REMOVE_BILL, CHKBOX_PRINT_BILL in same block. 
where user can select only one checkbox at a time. When one checked another one should be unchecked. Trigger in Oracle Forms 6i.

I wrote this on CHKBOX_REMOVE_BILL, when-checkbox-changed trigger

DECLARE

```
val number;
```

BEGIN

```
IF CHECKBOX_CHECKED(:BLK_REMOVE.CHKBOX_REMOVE_BILL) THEN
 val := 0 ; -- replace with your real unchecked value
 --:BLK_REMOVE.CHKBOX_PRINT_BILL := 1 ;
```

ELSE
     val := 1 ; -- replace with your real checked value
     --:BLK_REMOVE.CHKBOX_PRINT_BILL := 0 ;
  END IF ;

```
BEGIN

    IF CHECKBOX_CHECKED(:BLK_REMOVE.CHKBOX_REMOVE_BILL) <> false  THEN
        :BLK_REMOVE.CHKBOX_PRINT_BILL := 0 ;
    ELSE
        :BLK_REMOVE.CHKBOX_PRINT_BILL := 1 ;
    END IF ;

END;

EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
        call_note_alert('Error');
```

END;

I wrote this on CHKBOX_PRINT_BILL, when-checkbox-changed trigger
DECLARE

```
val number;
```

BEGIN

```
IF CHECKBOX_CHECKED(:BLK_REMOVE.CHKBOX_PRINT_BILL) THEN
 val := 1 ; -- replace with your real unchecked value
 :BLK_REMOVE.CHKBOX_REMOVE_BILL := 0 ;
```

ELSE
     val := 0 ; -- replace with your real checked value
     :BLK_REMOVE.CHKBOX_REMOVE_BILL := 1 ;
  END IF ;

BEGIN

```
    IF CHECKBOX_CHECKED(:BLK_REMOVE.CHKBOX_PRINT_BILL) <> false  THEN
        :BLK_REMOVE.CHKBOX_REMOVE_BILL := 0 ;
    ELSE
        :BLK_REMOVE.CHKBOX_REMOVE_BILL := 1 ;
    END IF ;

END;

EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
        call_note_alert('Error');
```

END;

///////
when I check one checkbox, both are selected

---

In my form there are two checkboxes named CHKBOX_REMOVE_BILL, CHKBOX_PRINT_BILL in same block named BLK_REMOVE. 
when form runs, user want to check only one at a time (like radio button).
how to write trigger on when-checkbox-changed ?

---

I had changed my code, now it's working properly

I wrote this code on CHKBOX_REMOVE_BILL, when-checkbox-changed trigger.
where CHKBOX_REMOVE_BILL checked value = 1, unchecked value = 0.

DECLARE

```
val number;
```

BEGIN

```
if(:BLK_REMOVE.CHKBOX_REMOVE_BILL = 0)then
    :BLK_REMOVE.CHKBOX_PRINT_BILL := 2;
else
    :BLK_REMOVE.CHKBOX_PRINT_BILL := 3;
end if;

EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
        call_note_alert('Error');
```

END;

I wrote this on CHKBOX_PRINT_BILL, when-checkbox-changed trigger.
where CHKBOX_PRINT_BILL checked value = 2, unchecked value = 3.

DECLARE

```
val number;
```

BEGIN

```
if(:BLK_REMOVE.CHKBOX_PRINT_BILL = 2)then
    :BLK_REMOVE.CHKBOX_REMOVE_BILL := 0 ; 
else
        :BLK_REMOVE.CHKBOX_REMOVE_BILL := 1 ;
end if;

EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
        call_note_alert('Error');
```

END;

Comment: What did you try so far? Please provide some code and a detailed description of your problem.

Comment: Easiest way is to have a trigger on `WHEN-CHECKBOX-CHECKED` which checks if the value of checkbox is that of checked and if that is so then disable the other checkbox.

Answer (score 2):

Use Radio Buttons instead of checkboxes